# Flutter application not displaying videos and GIFs when fetching data from WordPress

Tags: wordpress, flutter, dart

I'm developing a Flutter application that fetches data from WordPress using an API. The application successfully displays images and content from the WordPress posts, but I'm facing an issue with videos and GIFs. They are not getting displayed in the app.

I have tried the following approaches but haven't been successful:

Check if the URLs for the videos and GIFs are correct.
Verify that the WordPress API is returning the URLs for videos and GIFs correctly.
Ensure that I have the necessary permissions and internet connectivity to fetch the videos and GIFs.
Confirm that the video and GIF formats are supported by the Flutter application.
Despite these attempts, I still can't get the videos and GIFs to display.

Can anyone help me understand what could be causing this issue and suggest possible solutions or workarounds? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if any additional information is required. Thank you!

```
    class _WordPressPostsScreenState extends State<WordPressPostsScreen> {
  WordPressPosts postService = WordPressPosts();
  List<dynamic> posts = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    List<dynamic> fetchedPosts =
    await postService.getPostsByCategory(widget.categoryId);

    setState(() {
      posts = fetchedPosts;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: posts.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final post = posts[index];
        final title = post['title']['rendered'] ?? '';
        final content = post['content']['rendered'] ?? '';
        final media = post['_embedded'] != null &&
            post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'] != null &&
            post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'] is List &&
            post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'].isNotEmpty
            ? post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]
            : null;

        Widget mediaWidget;
        
        print('@@@@@@@ Post: ${posts}--------@@@@@@');
        

        if (media != null && media['media_type'] == 'image') {
          final imageUrl = media['source_url'] ?? '';
          mediaWidget = Image.network(imageUrl);
        } else if (media != null && media['media_type'] == 'video') {
          final videoUrl = media['source_url'] ?? '';
          mediaWidget = VideoWidget(videoUrl: videoUrl);
        } else if (media != null && media['media_type'] == 'gif') {
          final gifUrl = media['source_url'] ?? '';
          mediaWidget = Image.network(gifUrl);
        } else {
          print('Unknown media type: ${media['media_type']}');
          mediaWidget = SizedBox.shrink();
        }

        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: mediaWidget,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      title ?? '',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            subtitle: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                content?.replaceAll("<p>", "")?.replaceAll("</p>", "") ?? '',
                maxLines: 4,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => PostDetail(data: post),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


  class PostDetail extends StatelessWidget {
      final data;
      const PostDetail({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Better Investor - Trending Post"),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    data['title']['rendered'],
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (data['_embedded'] != null &&
                  data['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'] != null &&
                  data['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'] is List &&
                  data['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'].isNotEmpty)
                MediaWidget(media: data['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                  data['content']['rendered']
                      .toString()
                      .replaceAll("<p>", "")
                      .replaceAll("</p>", ""),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class MediaWidget extends StatelessWidget {
          final media;
          const MediaWidget({Key? key, required this.media}) : super(key: key);
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            if (media['media_type'] == 'image') {
              final imageUrl = media['source_url'] ?? '';
              return Image.network(imageUrl);
            } else if (media['media_type'] == 'video') {
              final videoUrl = media['source_url'] ?? '';
              return VideoWidget(videoUrl: videoUrl);
            } else if (media['media_type'] == 'gif') {
              final gifUrl = media['source_url'] ?? '';
              return Image.network(gifUrl);
            } else {
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            }
          }
        }
```

Print Statement returns this:

```
[{id: 3773, date: 2023-06-16T06:53:58, date_gmt: 2023-06-16T06:53:58, guid: {rendered: https://betterinvestor.in/?p=3773}, modified: 2023-06-27T05:15:19, modified_gmt: 2023-06-27T05:15:19, slug: demo-of-cover, status: publish, type: post, link: https://betterinvestor.in/2023/06/16/demo-of-cover/, title: {rendered: demo of cover}, content: {rendered: <div style="width: 640px;" class="wp-video"><!--[if lt IE 9]><script>document.createElement('video');</script><![endif]-->
I/flutter (17866): <video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-3773-1" width="640" height="360" preload="metadata" controls="controls"><source type="video/mp4" src="https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4?_=1" /><a href="https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4">https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4</a></video></div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide your MediaWidget too, since you said you have verified the URLs that are being extracted and passed to the MediaWidget, then probably the MediaWidget can be the source of the problem.

Comment: I have shared the code @RikSantra

Comment: My guess is that the last statement in your MediaWidget where you say
`else {
              return SizedBox.shrink();
            }`
the SizedBox.shrink() gets returned and so you can't see anything being displayed, try printing a statement before returning return SizedBox.shrink(); or return a text widget instead and see if that text widget gets displayed or the statement gets printed, this would mean that your if statements fail and directly go towards the else case

Comment: I just tried changing my code but I was able to parse image but not able to parse video @RikSantra

Comment: @VijaylaxmiShettar Again check if the else logic is working correctly, if the URL for the video shows up properly then it is probably some problem in the VideoWidget implementation.

Comment: The else logic is working properly and its printing null @RikSantra

Comment: @VijaylaxmiShettar if it is null, that means there is no URL of the video so therefore it won't load the video as well because the URL is null, check how you are retrieving the URL of the video.

Comment: @RikSantra As I'm fetching the data directly from the website I'm not giving the separate  url for image or video, I'm just providing the source url ,  it is fetching the image from source url but video is not displaying.

Comment: @VijaylaxmiShettar then there should be a problem in the VideoWidget in displaying the video then

Comment: @RikSantra for posts if I print I'm getting the response which I've shared in the code section. So how to fetch the video URL.

Comment: @VijaylaxmiShettar Well, you can see that the printed statement is an HTML tag, the URL to the video is in the `src` attribute of the HTML tag, you will have to parse out the src and then use the URL from it. right now you are directly giving the HTML tag of the video as the URL. You can use flutter's HTML package to do this easily.

Comment: @RikSantra I am already using html package still i am not able to fetch, so can you please provide with a sample code. Thanks